# SQL compare min value in one column with max date in different column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to find all records in Column A where, after sorting Column C in ascending order, Column D begins with a value other than the earliest date.

From the below example, I would want it to return records for Ex2 and Ex3 and not return records for Ex1.

**REVISED UPDATES/REQUIREMENTS:**

1) I would like it grouped by Column A and ordered by Column C.
2) I would like to find all records in Column A where the first value in Column D is not the lowest date.

```
Column A  Column B  Column C  Column D
--------  --------  --------  --------
  Ex1     Title A      1      2003/1/1
  Ex1     Title B      2      2003/2/2

  Ex2     Title C      3      2004/4/4
  Ex2     Title D      4      2004/3/3

  Ex3     Title E      5      2005/6/6
  Ex3     Title F      6      2005/5/5
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: "lower" and "greater" than what? Your examples "Ex.1","Ex.2","Ex.3" aren't columns, so how do you want to group these records?

Comment: @TimSchmelter See update above

Comment: @TimSchmelter I want it grouped by the examples.  Just decided to add those in as columns to simplify.

Comment: @Keven What defines "first" and "second" record for each example; is it column B? There's not an inherent order in a table; you need to specify which column(s) define the ordering. Also, you say you want true or false for each example, then say you want to return the records. Which is it?

Comment: @EsotericScreenName I see your points.  I just want to return the records that are true, and not return records that are false.  Thinking about how to word the whole "first" and "second" part...

Comment: @Keven Your comment on CriticalFix's answer indicates there might be many rows in each column A group. Do you want all rows from each group that satisfy the conditions, or do you want only the "greatest" row (whatever that means)? Re: your edit, is column C what defines "first" and "second" rows? Is column B involved in the filter or ordering? Your requirements still aren't clear. Better sample data and expected results would help.

Comment: Yes, Column C defines "first" and "second".  Column B should not be ordered or filtered (I suppose I should just remove it).

Comment: RE: Update #2: is this the only specification? If not, can you please claerly state all of the specifications for this query in a single place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to assume an ordering by [Column B], which you can make explicit in a self join:

```
SELECT t1.[Column A], t1.[Column B], t1.[Column C], t1.[Column D]
FROM YourTableName t1
JOIN YourTableName t2
ON t2.[Column A] = t1.[Column A]
AND t2.[Column B] > t1.[Column B]
WHERE t2.[Column C] > t1.[Column C]
AND t2.[Column D] < t1.[Column D]
```

This assumes there are exactly two rows where [Column A] = 'Ex1', etc.  If you have more than two rows with the same value in [Column A] you will probably find the results to be unexpected.

Note that the first two comparisons are part of the join condition, and the third and fourth comparisons are part of the WHERE clause.

UPDATE:

Working to changed requirements:  There may be twenty rows with [Column A] = 'Ex1'.  Return distinct values of [Column A] for which the lowest value of [Column C] is not in the same row as the lowest value of [Column D].  [Column B] is not relevant.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.[Column A]
FROM YourTableName t1
JOIN 
(SELECT [Column A], MIN([Column C]) AS MinC, MIN([Column D]) AS MinD
 FROM YourTableName
 GROUP BY [Column A]) t2
ON t2.[Column A] = t1.[Column A]
WHERE t1.[Column C] = t2.MinC
AND t1.[Column D] <> t2.MinD
```

This returns:

```
Column A
Ex1
```

For the following test table:

```
CREATE TABLE YourTableName
([Column A] VARCHAR(50),
[Column B] VARCHAR(50),
[Column C] INT,
[Column D] INT)
```

And test data:

```
INSERT INTO YourTableName
([Column A], [Column B], [Column C], [Column D])
VALUES ('Ex1', 'Title A', 1, 2)

INSERT INTO YourTableName
([Column A], [Column B], [Column C], [Column D])
VALUES ('Ex1', 'Title B', 2, 1)

INSERT INTO YourTableName
([Column A], [Column B], [Column C], [Column D])
VALUES ('Ex1', 'Title C', 3, 1)
```

Comment: If that's the case then this won't work for me.  The query needs to apply to examples where there are 1+ rows (up to about 20).

Comment: This is basically equivalent to the solution I provided

Comment: So you'll have maybe twenty rows with [Column A] = 'Ex.1'. You'll be ordering them by [Column B]. You'll only want to return the row with the lowest value of [Column B]. You'll want to return that row if (and only if) it also has the lowest value of [Column C] and the highest value of [Column D] among ALL of the records with [Column A] = 'Ex1'. Are those your specs?

Comment: I will group by Column A and order by Column C.  I want to return all examples from Column A where the "first" value in Column D is not the lowest value.

Comment: @keven you should clarify this in your original question so new people to this thread don't have to dig through all the comments to find this specification.

Comment: @criticalfix Thanks.  I will look it over.  Keep in mind that it should return only Ex2 and 3 and NOT Ex 1.

Comment: @Keven there's no reason ex1 shouldn't be returned given only the revised requirements. Unless you mean that this query should return all records in the table except those matching the columnA value tied to the earliest date in the entire table?

Comment: @Keven I provided my own test data, for which Ex1 should be returned.

Comment: @criticalfix I tested your statement but inserted my own examples and it gave me the desired results (see my fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b960d/1).  However, in your example the last field is a datatype of int, when it should be a datatype of datetime.

Comment: @criticalfix I also tested it out with DATETIME and that worked as well. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a4333/1

Comment: @Keven The choice of data type for Column D was not relevant to the query syntax and I opted to keep it simple.  I'm glad to see you could substitute test data as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

New answer specifically addressing the following specifications (which seem to comprise the problem now):

> UPDATE: I would like it grouped by Column A and ordered by Column C.
>
> UPDATE #2: I want to return all examples from Column A where the
>   "first" value in Column D is not the lowest value.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tableName a
WHERE a.columnD <> (
    SELECT min(columnD)
    FROM tableName b
    WHERE a.columnA=b.columnA
    )
ORDER BY a.columnC
```

Comment: Thanks for the response David.  I tried this out, but it wasn't giving me the results I wanted, so I decided to figure out why.  If you add in `HAVING a.RECORD_ID = MIN(RECORD_ID)` after the WHERE clause of your sub-query it will give me the desired results.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: record_id was not a column in the sample schema you gave us, so I have no idea what this is referring to in the original problem context. Anyway, glad I could help :)

Comment: woops, by RECORD_ID I mean columnC.

Answer (score 0):

This technique is called a "self join."

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tableName a, tableName b
WHERE a.column_a = b.column_a
AND a.column_c < b.column_c
AND a.column_d > b.column_d
```

This assumes that the values in column_a are filled down and there aren't actually nulls as you showed in your example.

Comment: This answer neglects part of the requirements: `all records where the first value is less than the second value`. There's no ordering in your answer, but the question calls for it.

Comment: I interpreted that differently. He specifies the filters he wants in his first paragraph and then clarifies the specific data that should be returned given the example in his second paragraph. I'll let OP chime in if this isn't satisfactory.

Comment: Also, Column A can't be the primary key. Think about what your query would do if it was - it would return no results. It's probably a foreign key to some other table in OP's use case.

Comment: You're right, removed the bit about column_a being primary key. Also, I think you are downvoting somewhat aggressively.

Answer (score 0):

Using ranking functions, it can be done something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ColumnA ORDER BY ColumnC) AS RankC
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ColumnA ORDER BY ColumnD) AS RankD
    FROM MyTable
) x
WHERE RankC <> RankD
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9df3b/6)**

Comment: This answer doesn't account for the ordering ("first" vs. "second" rows in each column A group) the question requires.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Yes it does. Having ranking on C column assures that.

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from table where C = 
(select MIN(D) from table) 
AND 
(select * from table where D = (select MAX(D) from table))
```

null means false
else true

Comment: This isn't going to yield the desired results. It will return either 0 or 1 records, not one from each example group.